# update facebook status on publish_post and not when post is updated in wordpress

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have created a wordpress plugin which updates my facebook status when a new post is published. But the problem is that it also updates my facebook status if I updates a post after editing it even though the post has already been published. How do I solve this issue.

Comment: Report a bug/feature request to the plugin author if you don't find the setting in the plugin to control that behaviour.

Comment: @hakre: He is the plugin author, and the fact that `publish_post` runs on updates is the intended behavior. As mentioned in my answer, the triggers for publishing of new articles are `new_to_publish`, `draft_to_publish`, and `future_to_publish`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running the trigger on `publish_post`, have it run on `new_to_publish`, `draft_to_publish`, and `future_to_publish`. Those three triggers run when a new post is added, when a draft post is published, and when a scheduled post is published.